# Add UIAlertController in a custom UITableViewCell in button click using swift code?

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols, uialertview, custom-cell

I have menuTablecontroller in which I took customcell  with two labels and another Inner tableviewcontroller . Now here in  Innertableview  I have ItemCustomcell   with two labels and a button. I have to add Alertviewcontroller on clicking this button.
 I have tried by creating protocols   into the menuTabletablecontroller set the delegate but its not working ..

**My menutableviewcontroller**

```
protocol customPostcodeAlertDelegate {
func showAlert(title:String,message:String)

}
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 func showAlert(title:String,message:String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Mode of Order", message:"", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
 .....

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subcatcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! SubcatTableViewCell

   return cell
  }
```

Now in SubcatTableViewCell i have a button on its custom cell named itemtableviewcell

**My SubcatTableViewCell**

```
class SubcatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    InnerTableView.delegate = self
    InnerTableView.dataSource = self

    InnerTableView.bounces = false

}
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemCell")as! ItemTableViewCell
   return cell 
 }
```

Now I set the delegate in itemtableviewcell like this

```
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: customPostcodeAlertDelegate?

@IBOutlet var itemName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var itemPrice: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func OrderBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.delegate?.showAlert("Choose Mode of Order", message: "")


}


 }
```

But after clicking orderpressed button the alertview controller not working..
where I am doing mistake or give me another idea to add the alertviewcontroller in custom tableview  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually set the delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemCell") as! ItemTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = // Your MenuTableViewController
    return cell 
 }
```

**EDIT WITH NOTIFICATIONS**

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showAlert(_:)), name: "showError", object: nil)
    }


    func showAlert(sender: NSNotification) {
        let title = sender.object!["title"]
        let message = sender.object!["message"]

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Mode of Order", message:"", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    ....
}

class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBAction func OrderBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showError", object: [ "message" : "A message", "title" : "A Title" ])
    }
}
```

Comment: it showing error there if I set the delegate like .....cell.delegate = MenuTableViewController

Comment: error is .. cannot assign  value of type MenuTablebiewController .Type to type customPostcodeAlertDelegate

Comment: I think you need two delegates, because you're two steps away: `ItemTableViewCell -> SubcatTableViewCell -> MenuTableViewController`. You want to communicatie between ItemTableViewCell and MenuTableViewController, so you need two delegates. You could also try using NSNotificationCenter to send a notification to MenuTableViewController.

Comment: Actually i have so many customization in AlertViewController.  thats y I am taking Alert so that i can apply my custom designs and more  things

Comment: thanks its working successfully using NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118206/discussion-between-pradip-kumar-and-jan-doornbos).

Answer (score 0):

You are not conforming **MenuTableViewController** to your protocol. You will have to conform it like  `MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController, customPostcodeAlertDelegate`

Then you can override its method  `showAlert`